# Query to filter the data in ODBC Source SSIS using variable

Tags: sql, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm writing the source query in ODBC source to filter the records on a column (nvarchar) to pull the incremental load.

In the SouceCodeExpression I wrote the following code.

"Select * from Source_AuthorizationHistory where UpdateDate >" + "'@[User::LastUpdate]'"

Here UpdateDate is nvarchar datatype coming from source, I have to filter the records from source based on the last updated date in the target. So, here @[User::LastUpdate] variable datatype is String

@[User::LastUpdate] = 
Select Convert(nvarchar,Cast((Max(ETL_updated)-1) as Date)) as LastUpdated from Target_AUTHORIZATIONHISTORY

Help me to write this source query expression

"Select * from Source_AuthorizationHistory where UpdateDate >" + "'@[User::LastUpdate]'"

I got the following error [ErrorCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXI4E.jpg)

Comment: You have your quotes in the wrong place.  You should take the trouble to press 'evaluate' in the expression editor and you'd see this does not result in a valid query.

Comment: Yes.. I corrected by evaluating..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your value for `@[User::LastUpdate]` is correct

You have this:

```
"Select * from Source_AuthorizationHistory where UpdateDate >" + "'@[User::LastUpdate]'"
```

You need to do this:

```
"Select * from Source_AuthorizationHistory where UpdateDate > (" +  @[User::LastUpdate] + ")"
```

as this expression will equate to this:

```
Select * from Source_AuthorizationHistory where UpdateDate > (Select Convert(nvarchar,Cast((Max(ETL_updated)-1) as Date)) as LastUpdated from Target_AUTHORIZATIONHISTORY)
```

Comment: [SQLCODE:
> <-12>:<A term expected, beginning with one of the following: identifier,
> constant, aggregate, $$, :, (, +, -, %ALPHAUP, %EXACT, %SQLSTRING,
> %SQLUPPER, %STRING, or %UPPER>] [Cache Error: <<SYNTAX>errdone+1^%qaqqt>]
> [Details: <FLoop - func = DQ>] [%msg: < SQL ERROR #12: A term expected,
> beginning with either of: identifier, constant, aggregate, $$, (, :, +, -,
> %ALPHAUP, %EXACT, %SQLSTRING,

Comment: when you run this query in SSMS does it return any data? Select * from Source_AuthorizationHistory where UpdateDate > (Select Convert(nvarchar,Cast((Max(ETL_updated)-1) as Date)) as LastUpdated from Target_AUTHORIZATIONHISTORY)

Comment: Actually they are 2 separate databases.. One in ODBC connection and one in SSMS so, I'm unable run this query..

Comment: so how are you using this query in SSIS?

Comment: I actually declared the variable @[User::LastUpdate] thought it will hold the result of this query (Select Convert(nvarchar,Cast((Max(ETL_updated)-1) as Date)) which is 2016-02-25 .. Simply, I assumed @[User::LastUpdate] = 2016-02-25

Comment: In Execute SQL task, (Select Convert(nvarchar,Cast((Max(ETL_updated)-1) as Date)) will be declared in avriable with OLEDB Target (Another adtabase)

Comment: ok that makes sense, and you're going to have a result variable and pass that into this: "Select * from Source_AuthorizationHistory where UpdateDate > " +  @[User::ResultVariable]